# Foreach is not getting all data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach

I am using foreach statement to get all data and print in table and also using ajax to get all zones and driver of that zone every row has different drivers according to his source but problem is when i load page it is showing me all data of users only in table but the zone and driver is showing me only one row other rows not showing me driver below is my code please tell me where i am wrong

```
                    <tbody>
                <?php
                $counter = 0;
                foreach($result as $user){?>

                <form action="<?php echo SURL?>dashboard/set_driver" method="POST">
                <tr>
                <td><?php get_username($user['client_id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['pickfrom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['dropat']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['pickdate'].' '.$user['picktime']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['distance']; ?></td>
                <input type="hidden" id="txtSource" value="<?php echo trim($user['pickfrom']); ?>">
                <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="driver_id" id="drivers_<?php echo $counter;?>"><option>Select Driver</option>
                </select>
                </div></td><input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="<?php echo $user['latitude'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longtitude" value="<?php echo $user['longtitude'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">

                <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Set Driver</button>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </form>
                <?php echo $div_id = '#drivers_'.$counter;?>


                <script>
                var map;
                var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $user['latitude'];?>, <?php echo $user['longtitude'];?>);

                function initialize() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.714760, 73.083160),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                <?php 
                $counter=0;
                if(!empty($zone)){
                foreach($zone as $findzone)
                {
                $exploded_data=explode('),',$findzone['zone_latlog']);
                $count=count($exploded_data);
                $zone_id = $findzone['id'];
                ?>  
                var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                map: map,
                paths: [
                <?php 
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                echo "new google.maps.LatLng".$exploded_data[$i]."),";
                }
                ?>
                ]
                });
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i=0; i<bermudaTriangle.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                bounds.extend(bermudaTriangle.getPath().getAt(i));
                }
                bounds.extend(coord1);
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: coord1
                });
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                map.setZoom(11);
                var result = checkInPolygon(marker1, bermudaTriangle);
                if(result)
                {

                var zone_id = <?php echo $zone_id;?>;
                alert(zone_id);
                var lati = $('#latitude').val();
                var longi = $('#longitude').val();
                $.ajax({        
                url: '<?php echo SURL;?>dashboard/check_driver/<?php echo $zone_id;?>/'+longi+'/'+lati,
                data: 'zone_id='+ zone_id+'&lati='+lati+'&longi='+longi,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                // alert(response);
                for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                alert(response[i].driver_name);
                $('<?php echo $div_id?>').append($('<option>', {
                value: response[i].driver_id,
                text: response[i].driver_name
                }));
                } 
                }
                }); 

                }
                <?php 
                }}?> 
                }

                function checkInPolygon(marker, polygon) {
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var html = "";
                if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), polygon)) {
                return true;
                } else {
                return false;
                }
                infowindow.setContent(html);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);

                }


                </script>

                <?php
                $counter++;
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
```

if i write script outside foreach i show me single data of driver and if i write inside result is same.

Comment: can you print the $results variable

Comment: yes it show me all result

Comment: i can't write all result here but one array is     Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 41 [driver_id] => 0 [client_id] => 54 [pickdate] => 2017-05-16 [pickfrom] => Bahria Town, Rawalpindi, Punjab, Pakistan [dropat] => PWD Housing Society, Rawalpindi, Punjab, Pakistan [distance] => 17.0 km [picktime] => 15:53:15 [droptime] => [status] => pending [ip] => ::1 [latitude] => 33.495896 [longtitude] => 73.10563009999998 ) [1] =>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your foreach loop make it dynamic, first count the result, then pass that to array chunk then a for loop for the number you got and inside it one foreach

Comment: still getting one result only? bro can you paste the output in the question section? let it be big. i cant understand if i dont see the result

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/YmeUS   this second image i get result in second row but first row is empty...

Comment: your data format is messed up, the data is coming in different arrays and not a single one, thus the problem

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: first of all tell what this shows echo(count($result ));

Comment: what is the output?? tell me

Comment: it show me  2 2 as i write foreach($result as $k => $user){ echo count($result);    output is 2 2

Comment: first break the array into 2 arrays then use foreach for each one

Comment: can you please write code just demo code for understanding?

Comment: $i = array_chunk($result,2);
then foreach($i[0] as $ user){ 
your code
}
foreach($i[1] as $user){
your code
}

Comment: if array greater 2 than what can i do?

Comment: make it dynamic, first count the result, then pass that to array chunk then a for loop for the number you got and inside it one foreach